# Scala Type MisMatch Error in spark

Tags: scala

I have created the following function:

```
 def mapToPers(inTuple: (String, String, String), 
               v: ((Double, Double, Double, Double, Double),
                   Map[Double,
                       (Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)])) = {

      val (prod: String, market: String, week: String) = inTuple
      val result = for (cumePeriod <- cumePeriods) yield {
        val (per, weekList) = cumePeriod
        if (weekList.contains(week)) ((prod, market, per), v)        
  }
 result
}
```

When  I call it, it gives error of type mismatch:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type type mismatch;  found   :
>   ((String, String, String), ((Double, Double, Double, Double, Double),
>   Map[Double,(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)])) =>
>   **scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any]**  required: (((String, String, String), ((Double, Double, Double, Double, Double),
>   Map[Double,(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]))) =>
>   **TraversableOnce[?]**

Comment: Please, what's the output `println(inTuple)` and `println(cumePeriods)`. Also from where does `v` come from?

Comment: What is the type of cumePeriods ?

Comment: Instead of creating so crazy tuples , you'd better to create separate `case class` for each of them. It much easier to bug fix/investigate.

Answer (score 3):

You clearly have a problem with nested tuples. Check the parentheses:

found :

```
(
  (String, String, String), 
  (
    (Double, Double, Double, Double, Double), 
    Map[Double,(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]
  )
) => scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any]
```

required:

```
(
  (
    (String, String, String), 
    (
      (Double, Double, Double, Double, Double), 
      Map[Double,(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]
    )
  )
) => TraversableOnce[?]
```

So I see one more level of nesting. Hard to spot given the very confusing types, I would recommend you use some case classes here.

Edit: BTW, I Spotted something else. The `if` you are using does not have an else, so the for comprehension will not know what to yield exactly. You might want to yield only after checking:

```
val result = for { 
  (per, week_list) <- cumePeriods
  if week_list.contains(week)
}
  yield ((prod, market, per), v)
```